# What is the difference between reading in text mode and binary mode, when checking checksums using `sha1sum`?

Tags: checksum, sha

I often compute checksums of files downloaded from the Internet, using `shasum` family of commands, without paying attention to the mode for reading. In particular, `sha1sum` usually defaults to text mode for applications.

What is the difference between reading in text mode and binary mode, when checking checksums using `sha1sum`?

```
~/Downloads$ sha1sum --help
Usage: sha1sum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Print or check SHA1 (160-bit) checksums.

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

  -b, --binary         read in binary mode
  -c, --check          read SHA1 sums from the FILEs and check them
      --tag            create a BSD-style checksum
  -t, --text           read in text mode (default)
  -z, --zero           end each output line with NUL, not newline,
                       and disable file name escaping

The following five options are useful only when verifying checksums:
      --ignore-missing  don't fail or report status for missing files
      --quiet          don't print OK for each successfully verified file
      --status         don't output anything, status code shows success
      --strict         exit non-zero for improperly formatted checksum lines
  -w, --warn           warn about improperly formatted checksum lines

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

The sums are computed as described in FIPS-180-1.  When checking, the input
should be a former output of this program.  The default mode is to print a
line with checksum, a space, a character indicating input mode ('*' for binary,
' ' for text or where binary is insignificant), and name for each FILE.

GNU coreutils online help: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/sha1sum>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) sha1sum invocation'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None.

At least judging by the answer to the similar question on [the difference between text and binary in md5sum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127961/355088).

It appears it flags are for standards compliance or something